# Require transit Visa?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, lhr, iranian-citizens

I am an Iranian and traveling to Oslo (Norway) from Tehran (Iran) by British Airways via London Heathrow Airport. Do I need a Transit Visa?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Are you sure of that? Last time I checked, Schengen visas did _not_ exempt from the DATV requirement in the UK (even though, for example, US visas do). The only time Schengen visas have this effect is for groups of Chinese travelers on an Approved Destination Scheme package tour.